# change detection ;application.tick is recursively called ? why

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-changedetection, ngzone

i have a parent component A and child component b  and service c for loading the loading pop up service  in success and failure.

Have a button  called as newchanges in B child component and b component emit the value and call the function in a component and there have a service call , in the service call.

while click on the child component b newchanges button continiously, i am getting below error.application.tick is recursively called .

if i am not using application.tick , the loading diolog is not close, therefore i have used in the application ref in service. it is a global service for all the modules.

can any one help to resolve:

this is the loader service used in service call sucess and failure for close the loader.

```
exitLoader = ():void => {

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('tick1');
          this.matLoader.close();

          this.applicationRef.tick();
        }, 50);

}
```

i need to close the loader that is a service which is used in another service success and failure , when i am not using application ref it is not closing so i have used this after this i am click continiously call the service get an mentioned error.

and i have tried another option  using zone , loader not close:

```
 // setTimeout(() => {
      //   this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      //     this.matLoader.close();
      //   });
      // }, 100);
```

Comment: can you include some code which can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: can you able to come on any chat, i think some problem in workflow, cannot explain in stackoverflow one more question how to use change detection in service not component